Why is my SD card showing less capacity than advertised?
I bought a 64GB Samsung EVOPlus SD card from a vendor on Ebay the other day.
!ddg 64 gb to gib

A screenshot of the website duckduckgo.com showing the conversion of 64 gigabytes to gibibytes, yielding a value of 59.60464:

~$ sudo fdisk -l
<snip>
Disk /dev/sdd: 58.22 GiB, 62510333952 bytes, 122090496 sectors
Disk model: USB-MSDC DISK A 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1          32 122090495 122090464 58.2G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)

I can provide the output of another, older 64GB Samsung card also:
~$ sudo fdisk -l
<snip>
Disk /dev/sdd: 59.69 GiB, 64088965120 bytes, 125173760 sectors
Disk model: USB-MSDC DISK A 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1       32768 125173759 125140992 59.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

I was wondering why the actual size is less than the advertised size by over a gigabyte?

perhaps it's a matter of marketing - nobody would buy a 62.5GB drive :p

Are you sure it's a genuine drive? I'd expect the device model to say something a little more "Samsung"

The age old question. First there's the 1000 used for marketing, but 1024 used by computers. Then there's filesystem overhead and finally there might be some overprovisioning done for wear leveling purposes.

@Mokubai Even so, manufacturers often reserve some space for wear leveling or bad sector management.  Formatted capacity for 64GB SD cards are most commonly reported to be around 58.5GB, which is very close to the number here. EMTEC, a large SD Card seller, lists there formatted capacities here (https://www.emtec-international.com/en/faq/memory-cards/what-usable-capacity-my-memory-card) and it even shows less free space for 64GB variants. It could still be a knock-off drive, but i dont find the reported numbers to be a strong indicator of that. Knock-offs often are much scammier than this.

@Mokubai Giga (G) is actually a Systeme Internationale (SI) prefix and thus always denotes 1x10^9. Gibi (Gi) is also an SI prefix, denoting 1x8^9. You can cross-factor to come up with ~59.60464GiB to GB.
I think you have confused the value in a random comment for the conversion between 64 GB -> GiB.

@Silvee thank you for that. I've amended my answer to include the output from a different drive, this one is a close match (slightly over) to the conversion from 64GB -> GiB ~ = 59.60464 GiB. Perhaps I can attribute the difference to the factors you've mentioned, thanks.
